# EF ASP.net app connects to db even after connection strings are deleted in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Can somebody tell me how EF/asp.net caches db entries?  I have a simple mvc3 project hitting a sqlserverexpress db.  I want to change the setting in the webconfig to point to a new db but even if I change the connection strings or even delete the section the app still connects to the old database.

Comment: chances are you changed the setting in the wrong config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is a nice thing, but it will do some things without telling you.

You haven't given us much info, but if you're using EF Code First then your connectionstring name must match the name of the DB Context file. So if you have MoviesContext as the DB Context then you should have the same name for the connectionstring.

EF Code First uses a lot of conventions so if it doesn't find a connection string named as the DB Context it will try to connect to a SQLExpress (doesn't care if there is not one installed) and will look for/create the database with a very long name: Namespace.MovieContext.

Note:  EF Code First might have gone off and created a database based on your POCO classes, if that is what you have done.

There is no caching involved in this case, it is just that EF Code First created a database for you...

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Apologies for the lack of information.  Basically, I was using code first, MVC3, EF4.1 less other details.  =)  Your post is correct in that since I was using code first and not passing any named params to the base class DbContext constructor.  Therefore, EF looks for the fully qualified named space for the DbContext class name:  NameSpace.DbContextClassedName.  Thanks again!